# PHP MySQLI Select multi columns returning null

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to retrieve 2 columns from my database with the following prepared statement:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT script, work_instruction FROM ".$table." WHERE category='".$category."' AND sub_category='".$sub_category."' AND issue='".$issue."'");
```

Whenever I use this query, the PHP is returning `null` to my webpage, even though the data is present in the DB. However, the following statement **does** work (Same for work_instruction):

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT script FROM ".$table." WHERE category='".$category."' AND sub_category='".$sub_category."' AND issue='".$issue."'");
```

Once I prepare the statement I execute and loop through my results, before returning them. I think the problem may lie here, but am not sure.

```
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($results);

while($statement->fetch()){
    array_push($myArr, $results);
}

$statement->free_result();
echo json_encode($myArr);
```

Here is an example of what my table looks like:
[image]

---

Here is the entire function, just in case you need to see more:

```
// Responsible for generating queries to the database
// and returning the data collected
function query($conn, $column) {    
    $myArr = array();
    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $sub_category = $_POST['sub_category'];
    $issue = $_POST['issue'];

    switch ($column) {
        case 'category':
            $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM ".$table);
            break;

        case 'sub_category':
            $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM ".$table." WHERE category='".$category."'");
            break;

        case 'issue':
            $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT issue FROM ".$table." WHERE category='".$category."' AND sub_category='".$sub_category."'");
            break;

        //This does not work
        case 'script':
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT script, work_instruction FROM ".$table." WHERE category='".$category."' AND sub_category='".$sub_category."' AND issue='".$issue."'");
        break;

        //This does work
        case 'work_instruction':
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT work_instruction FROM ".$table." WHERE category='".$category."' AND sub_category='".$sub_category."' AND issue='".$issue."'");
        break;

        case 'doc_link':
            //$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($results);

    while($statement->fetch()){
        array_push($myArr, $results);
    }

    $statement->free_result();
    echo json_encode($myArr);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to simplify your query function and add in error reporting.

```
function query($conn, $column) {    
    $myArr = array();
    $table = '`' . trim($_POST['table']) . '`';
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $sub_category = $_POST['sub_category'];
    $issue = $_POST['issue'];
    $selects = array(
       'category' => 'SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM ' . $table,
       'sub_category' => 'SELECT DISTINCT `sub_category` FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE category = ?',
       'issue' => 'SELECT DISTINCT `issue` FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE category = ? AND sub_category = ?',
       'script' => 'SELECT `script`, `work_instruction` FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE category = ? AND sub_category = ? AND issue = ?',
       'work_instruction' => 'SELECT `work_instruction` FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE category = ? AND sub_category = ? AND issue = ?'
    );
    if (true === isset($selects[$column])) {
       $statement = $conn->prepare($selects[$column]);
       switch ($column) {
          case 'sub_category':
             $statement->bind_param('s', $category);
             break;
          case 'issue':
             $statement->bind_param('ss', $category, $sub_category);
             break;
          case 'work_instruction':
          case 'script':
             $statement->bind_param('sss', $category, $sub_category, $issue);
             break;
       }
       if (!$statement->execute()) {
           trigger_error('Error executing MySQL query: ' . $statement->error);
       }
       $results = $statement->get_result();
       while ($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
           $myArr[] = $row;
       }
       $results->free();
       $statement->close();
   } else {
       trigger_error('Unknown column specified. Expected one of: "' . implode('", "', array_keys($selects)) . '" received "' . $column . '"');
   }
   echo json_encode($myArr);
}
```

Outside of your using `bind_result` Testing the query I return data fine, so if you are still having issues after changing this, I believe it would be something to do with the variable values. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bfb79/2

In order to identify the issue we would need an example of your table structure (columns and values) as close to actual values as possible, like in the SQL fiddle I linked.

Along with the variable values being sent to the query to fill in table, category, sub_category, and issue. Again like the SQL fiddle I linked.

Unless you use `$statement->store_result()` you don't need to call `$statement->free_result()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php As opposed to freeing the memory allocated by `$statement->get_result` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

Comment: Thank you for the great post. I am attempting to make these changes in my code, no luck yet :)

Here is your fiddler example made to fit my schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c4b3/1/0

I also updated my post with an IMG of my table.

Comment: When I run your code, I get a response code of "500" that occurs when calling the "get_results()" function. Any ideas why?

Comment: Alright, with some minor tweaking I was able to get this snippet working!
Thank you for the effort and for the excellent answer. For some reason, the get_result() function was not working. I ended up using bind_result() instead

Comment: I assume you're running PHP older than 5.3 which is when `get_result()` was introduced. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: I am using: PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 17:39:00)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem in your code in terms of syntax. But you might want to change the way you are passing the parameters to your prepared statements. The current approach you are using is insecure and you don't actually get the benefits of using prepared statements at all.

Try the following code and see If your problem is resolved. I think this should work unless there is a problem with a values you are passing. In here I have assumed that all of your parameters are string. If it's integer you can change the 's' in bind_param to 'i'.

```
<?php
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT script, work_instruction FROM {$table} WHERE category = ? AND sub_category = ? AND issue= ?");
$statement->bind_param('sss', $category, $sub_category, $issue); // s = string
$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->get_result();
while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($myArr, $row);
}

echo json_encode($myArr);
```

Comment: Would this work given the following scenario: User must select a tool, once tool is selected the DB is queried for categories for that tool, when the category is selected on the webpage, the DB is queries for sub_category, etc. etc..

In other words, the database is queried in a specific order and doesn't query everything at the same time necessarily

Comment: @EvanBechtol The parameters protects you from SQL injection attempts. You would need to add `bind_param` to each of your case conditions as appropriate.

Comment: @fyrye Awesome, thanks very much! SO basically, each case needs to have the same basic structure as the code that n00b has laid out, then at the end execute and loop through results?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code

1. It is wide open to SQL injections
2. It lacks proper error reporting.
3. Minor syntax issue (that should have been reported, if you paid any attention to the option 2).

As you imagine that first two aren't important at all, here goes solution for the third: with `bind_result()` you have to bind variables for all the fields selected.

As a side note, if you have to change the table name dynamically, it's a BIG RED SIGN flashing "Bad database design".

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is my first time using PHP to connect to databases, so I don't have experience with SQL injections yet. But, knowing this now I will adjust my code.